# Escape characters in Cucumber step definition

Tags: escaping, cucumber, bdd, gherkin, cucumber-java

I have following steps that I am using for [Cucumber-jvm](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm). How do I escape certain characters in my step definitions?

```
When user verifies if ABC widget exists
Then the 'The 7 Things $channel' label is displayed
```

In this case I need to escape *7* and *$* as a regular string.

Comment: Why do you think you need to escape the digit?

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth 7 or any other number has no numerical contextual value in my step. It is just a text label that needs to be verified.

Comment: You mean that you want "7" and "$channel" to be parameters to the step?

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth Nope not individual parameters just one string parameter as "The 7 Things $channel". Later in my code I do some string replacement between $channel with some other value. I guess '7' and '$' characters probably threw you off.

Comment: Right, because digits aren't special in regexps. See if this edit makes sense ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this,

```
Then the /'The 7 Things $channel' label is displayed/
```

Corresponding Step def would be,

```
 @Then("^the /'The 7 Things \\$channel' label is displayed/$")
   public void the_The_Things_$channel_label_is_displayed() throws Throwable {
      System.out.println("hello");
   }
```