# How to escape "?" in Cucumber Java?

Tags: regex, gherkin, cucumber-java

I am using Cucumber java. In a step definition, I would like to use a question mark as a string and not to be considered as a regex, which means I need to escape it. I have seen this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615714/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-cucumber-step-definitions) about escaping and tried to apply :

```
@When("^I make PUT /service/(.*)/url\\?pathParam=(.*)$")
```

In the feature file, the step would appear as :

```
When I make PUT /service/<string>/url\?pathParam=<string>
```

(please note the backslash in front of the question mark)

I would like to get :

```
When I make PUT /service/<string>/url?pathParam=<string>
```

How should I write my step so the question mark is correctly escaped, with no additional character added?

Edit :
Using a single backslash in front of the question mark results with an illegal escape character in string literal exception. The curious thing is that escaping a quote with a single backslash anywhere in the step doesn't display this exception.

Comment: Why then use ``\\`` at all? Write it as `@When("^I make PUT /service/(.*)/url?pathParam=(.*)$")` However, I feel you really need to escpae the `?` as `\?` to match a literal `?` with a regex.

Comment: not escaping the question mark makes it recognized as a regex, and then, it disappears on the step, giving : When I make PUT /service/<string>pathParam=<string>

Comment: Ok, try a usual workaround: `@When("^I make PUT /service/(.*)/url[?]pathParam=(.*)$")` - a character class.

Comment: It doesn't work, result is : When I make PUT /service/<string>[]pathParam=<string>

Comment: Is `?` a special character in your environment? How should be written so that `?` was a literal?

Comment: It happens for any Meta-character, for example, I have the same issue with $. For non meta-character, escaping works fine. From the solution mentionned in my question, it seems necessary to use slashes, but I already use it to define the url in my step definition.

Comment: The stepdef you tried works perfectly for me with [cucumber-jvm](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#java), that is the step is executed and the strings are passed to the glue. I guess your question is not about escaping in Cucumber Java, but rather about making your IDE integration to show autocompletion without escaped characters when you typing a feature?

Comment: Thanks Mykola, indeed, this is what I am figuring out too with different answers I am getting. Can you please tell me which version of cucumber-jvm you use and which IDE you use (+plugins)?

Comment: I checked [the latest revision of skeleton project](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/tree/e1a7dbb74379fa51ce0590aafcd1c935e27f5a8f) which uses cucumber 1.2.4. Would work with much earlier versions as well - java regex doesn't change often. I use IntelliJ with Cucumber for java 143.382 where the gherkin autocomplete *does not* work properly. But this is an old issue of the Idea plugin rather than cucumber, IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

if you're trying to achieve this `When I make PUT /service/<string>/url?pathParam=<string>`:

```
@When("^I make PUT /service/\"(.*?)\"/url\\?pathParam=\"(.*?)\"$")
```

useful info here related to this: [How to escape special characters in Cucumber step definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615714/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-cucumber-step-definitions)

Comment: The link you provide is the one I mention in my initial question. Your solution gives : When I make PUT /service/"<string>"\?pathParam="<string>" . It displays quotes and a backslash that I don't want to have.

Comment: I edited the initial question to mention that escaping quotes works fine, but escaping question mark doesn't. Trying o escape $ anywhere in the step definition results with \$, not like in the link you provide. It seems to be related to slashes added at the beginning and end of step definition. Issue in my case is that I am already using slashes to define the url I am using in the step definition. From the link solution, what is the use of the slashes?

Comment: updated my answer.. pls check if i understood correctly

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It gives : When I make PUT /service/".*"/url\?pathParam=".*"

Comment: there is no url mentioned in my step.. this will give you `I make PUT /service/"test"?pathParam="test"`

Comment: Your latest edit displays : When I make PUT /service/".*"/url\?pathParam=".*"

Comment: try copy and paste it shouldn't give `url\?path`.. working for me

Comment: Copy paste provides same results than my previous comment. Could it be related to cucumber dependencies or IDE? I am using IntelliJ with plugin Gherkin v141.178, cucumber for java v141.178. I use following dependencies : cucumber-spring, cucumber-java, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-core all from info.cukes v1.2.4

Comment: Suggested step definition is wrong as it requires extra quotes from url.