# Ignoring special character in the cucumber parameterized data

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I have a cucumber scenario in which I have to pass the data, and the data contains special characters. And when I execute it fails at the assertion.

Below is my scenario:

```
Scenario Outline: ABTA data  
Given a customer is on the "<respective>" page  
When the customer scrolls down to the bottom of the page  
Then the customer should be able to view the following text with ABTA logo  
|We're part of XXX Group - one of the world's leading| 

Example:
|Home Page|
```

The data which I am passing after the Then step "We're part of XXX Group - one of the world's leading" has 2 special characters and because of that my assertion fails.

Can anyone please let me know as of how can I ignore the special characters in the data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to better define your code

```
Scenario Outline: ABTA data
  Given a customer is on the <respective>
  When the customer scrolls down to the bottom of the page
  Then the customer should be able to view the following text with ABTA logo
<expected>

  Examples:
    | respective | expected                                             |
    | Home Page  | We're part of XXX Group - one of the world's leading |
```

And the cucumber step should be defined as

```
@Given("^a customer is on the (.*)$") {...}   

@Then("^the customer should be able to view the following text with ABTA logo (.*)$") {...}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax is wrong. If you check the [documentation](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/) you will see that the proper way is different. It's the official documentation from Cucumber.

There is also one more issue like yours. Please check this too: [Escape characters in Cucumber step definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615714/escape-characters-in-cucumber-step-definition)